# What is the best way to create and maintain a movie database?

Tags: database-design, web-applications, frameworks, content-management-system

There are similar questions, but none answers what I really need. I actually don't want to create as long as there is already one ready-made.

If so please guide me on the right direction. This isn't anything big, just to maintain my own collection.

So basically:

1. Is there a ready-made CMS (or a plugin for a CMS) that does this, even a framework with this kind of web application is good?
2. If not what will be the quickest way to implement one?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Most CMS would be able to maintain a movie database, but i don't think there is any CMS whith this purpose in mind. It all depends an what frameworks and environments you have availible

2.
With ruby on rails setup, do

```
rails my_movies
cd my_movies
script/generate scaffold movies title:string rating:integer
```